# Can we validate DB connection from Ant script?

Tags: database, jdbc, ant

My ant script accepts command line arguments for a database. For example it accepts db type, url, username, password etc.

I wish to validate the parameters by doing a test connection from my ANT script.

Is it possible ? if so how ?

Answer (score 0):

Most databases allow some test query to a virtual table.

Mysql for example: select 1 from dual;

Executing this query with the ant sql-task would abort the build if the connection does't work.

May this works for you.

[Ant manual sql task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html)